# Is it possible to create a Flash AS3 Custom Filter(BitmapFilter) without PixelBender

Tags: actionscript-3, image-processing

I'm here because I just can't believe that it's not possible to create
a custom Flash `BitmapFilter` without using the PixelBender.

Anyone knows if there is someway to do so?

The Flash have some native filters like:

- GlowFilter;
- DropShadowFilter;
- BlurFilter;
- etc.

I want to be able to use it like this:

```
var myBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
var myCustomFilter:CustomFilter = new CustomFilter();
myBitmap.filters = [myCustomFilter];
```

But I would like to extend the class `BitmapFilter` creating my own filters!

Comment: You can manipulate the pixels via bitmapdata as you wish...

Comment: But I would like to do something like:  MySprite.filters = [new MyCustomFilter()];

Comment: The answer is no. You have to use Pixel Bender.

Comment: Pixel Bender is pretty great, but Flash calculates PB Filters all on the CPU, not the GPU (at least as of CS5,) thus killing the performance. I'm with Nevitones, if there is a way to create high-performing filters for Flash, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to look and behave like the other (PixelBender) filters, then yes, you do have to write it in PixelBender - but what's wrong with doing this? It's easier than it looks and it's quite fun to experiment with.

You can manipulate pixels in BitmapData class using transforms (and filters) if you want, but the speed difference will be significant when compared to a normal filter, don't be expecting to build real-time effects which run smoothly! People use PixelBender filters to delegate intensive maths work to the GPU because it's so much faster than AS3 - if you want any real-time filter effects, and even if you don't, PixelBender is the sensible option.

Check it out:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible.**

James Ward created a library named **pbjAS** to do that!
Code samples and library here: [Announcing pbjAS – An ActionScript 3.0 Pixel Bender Shader Library](http://www.jamesward.com/2009/04/29/announcing-pbjas-an-actionscript-3-pixel-bender-shader-library/)